# Showing return values in standard out of Lua interpreter on Windows

Tags: lua

I am starting Lua and using the luaforwindows distribution.

In the Lua interpreter, it irks me that I have to use `print()` all the time to inspect values.

I see the interpreter on http://luatut.com/ prints values to standard out without the need for `print()`.

How can I achieve the same thing in the Windows interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something called iLua (Friendly Lua Command Line) in the luaforwindows distribution, which just runs `lua -lilua`, which seems to include some more user-friendly enhancements to the interpreter.

This feeds return values straight to standard out.

Answer (score 2):

You return values from the Lua interpreter as follows:

```
return "Hello World!"
```

There's a shorthand form as well:

```
= "Hello World!"
```

This tells the Lua interpreter to `print` the value.

Comment: Thanks, the = shortcut is handy. However, how does the online interpreter always print out the values?

Comment: The online interpreter used by http://luatut.com/ allows you to print out values without having to return them. However the main Lua interpreter does not. Hence you have to return the value you want to print.

Comment: Thanks, see my answer about -lilua. Guess it makes some enhancements to the interpreter.